# Calling a SP which has Insert Statement and returns a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

Is it possible to call a stored procedure which will insert the details first and at the end will return a table.  At present I have written two stored procedures for it: one for inserting and the other for getting the details. Now I'm trying to do both at the same time.

I'm using `ExecuteScalar` for inserting and `ExecuteDataSet` for selecting.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

If your stored procedure returns data using a SELECT (of course, I suppose that you need to read that data) then you should use the SqlDataAdapter with its Fill method or an SqlDataReader using the ExecuteReader on the SqlCommand

**ExecuteReader:**

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(...))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, cn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cn.Open()
    using(SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(r.Read())
        {
            // read every row and use the field values .....
        }

    }    
}
```

**SqlDataAdapter.Fill:**

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(...))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, cn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cn.Open()
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        // DataTable filled with the data returned by the last SELECT in your SP
        ......
    }    
}
```

The [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) or [SqlDataAdapter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter).Fill will execute the stored procedure without looking at what the stored procedure does, but they expect that some kind of tabular data will be returned to loop over it

Answer (score 0):

You write a procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Name
(
 //PARAMETES
)
AS
BEGIN

//INSERT STATEMENT

//SELECT STATEMENT

END
```

and call ExecuteDataSet()

Comment: I have created the SP. But my problem is calling that SP from C# code.

Answer (score -2):

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnectio(...)
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procName", cn)
 {
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 }
```